# Is the set of all sets of bit strings countably infinite, finite, or uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I’m not sure how to interpret “the set of all sets of bit strings.” Does this mean I could have some set like this:

[image]

Further, if this is the case, could I say that I can order the elements from smallest set to largest set, where each element itself is already ordered from least amount of bits to greatest, and say the overall set is countably infinite?

Comment: No, you can't .  If you accept infinite bit strings there are already uncountably many of them.

Comment: A heuristic you can use to determine whether a set is countable is that it is countable if each of its elements has a finite description. (I wrote a [blog post](https://blog.math.coffee/post/20181115/countable-sets/) about this a couple of weeks ago.) A set of bit strings may be infinite, so it's reasonable to expect that the set of all sets of bit strings is uncountable. (But then, of course, you have to prove it—see the answers below for help with that!)

Comment: Your interpretation of what "set of sets of" means is right. But they're not countable—see below for why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How many strings?**

(i) If you're only allowing finite strings, then each one is simply an integer expressed in binary, and the set of strings is countably infinite.

(ii) If you're allowing infinite strings,  then pairing every real number in $(0,1)$ with its binary representation tells you that they're uncountably infinite since there are uncountably many real numbers in $(0,1)$ and each can be represented by a string.

**How many sets of strings?**

If there are only countably-infinitely many strings, then for each set of strings you can construct an infinitely long binary number which contains 1 or 0 as its $n$th bit depending on whether the $n$th string is included. By the argument in (ii), there are uncountably many such numbers. Each is paired with one of the sets of strings, so there are uncountably many sets of strings.

If the strings themselves are uncountable then the sets of strings are too, since for each string there is a set containing just that string and you've got to at least have all those sets.

So either way, there are uncountably many sets of strings.

**Note:** The full argument would need refining a bit, because the integers actually have multiple representations (just add some zeros at the start) and so do some real numbers (similar to $0.49999. . . = 0.5 = 0.50000. . .$ in decimal).

Answer (score 2):

You have to decide whether bit strings are all of finite length or include countably infinite ones.  In the first case there are $\aleph_0$ of them, in the second case there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ of them.  You should have proved this already.  If $S$ is the set of bit strings, you are being asked $|P(P(S))|$.  Each power set operation corresponds to raising $2$ to the power of the size of the set.

Comment: I don't think he **has** to decide that in order to know whether there are countably many sets—since there are uncountably many anyway.

Comment: @timtfj:  It is uncountable, but a different uncountable infinity if you start with infinite length strings.  You are correct that if it is multiple choice, uncountable is easy to come to.

Comment: Sure. I just meant that it's not strictly necessary to know which cardinality it is, since it has to be an uncountable one. I was being pedantic about whether "have to" is strictly true.